# Display the output of a function in a <div> in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below code is in Web Form aspx.cs file and needs to be displayed in front end. So how to loop inside div tags?

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
{
    Response.Write(row["Content"].ToString());
    Response.Write("&nbsp&nbsp");
    Response.Write(row["Page"].ToString());
    Response.Write("<br/>");             
}
```

Comment: `Response.Write("<div>"); foreach ... {}; Response.Write("</div>");` ?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Web forms or MVC?  Aspx or razor?

Comment: @AlexK. but i have a different layout in my design, so it doesn't helps, i need to display the output in a particular div with div id = "div1"

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea in web forms, aspx where the code is placed in a different file

Comment: `<div id="div1" runat="server">` on the page and `div1.InnerHtml = "My Content"` on the codebehind?

Comment: @NateBarbettini i tried this, but its not working -

foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
            {
                div1.InnerHtml = row["Content"].ToString();
                Response.Write("&nbsp&nbsp");
                div1.InnerHtml = row["Page"].ToString();          
                Response.Write("<br/>");
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to say something similar to NateBarbettini, but his answer is simpler. So you should do this:

In your .aspx file have your div declared like this:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

And in your .cs code behind, in your Page_Load event, do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRowView row in dv)             
    sb.Append(row["Content"].ToString() + "&nbsp&nbsp" + row["Page"].ToString() + "<br/>");
div1.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks alot, the code works. However, the text which appears to be right aligned. I tried using -

sb.Append(row["Content"].ToString() + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + row["Page"].ToString() + "<br/>".PadRight(100));

but it does not works, even if i change the parameters of PadRight()

Comment: You should post another question about that.